# Boosting fields based on query in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing

I have default boost values on the field. Can I have the boost values based on the query itself?

Example: My search handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="qf">
  A^1.0 B^0.6 C^1.2
      </str>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

which boosts the fields A, B, C with predefined static values. I want these values to be based on the query itself. 
Something like.

```
A^1.0 B^0.6 C^myfunction(q)
```

Can it be done? Seems like functional query can help, but I cannot understand their syntax based on the documentation.

Comment: what sort of logic do you want your myfunction to handle? Do you want to emphasize some 'list of keywords' more than others?

Comment: I like to use a webserver+FastCGI to send user queries to a python script which will in turn forward it to Solr.  This approach of would let you implement "myFunction(q)" in Python if you're more comfortable with that.

Comment: kali, for some specific queries, I want to give more boost to some fields. Any take on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boosting a Term](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Boosting%20a%20Term) in your query. For example you have query "A B" if you what to boost term A, you should write your query "A^1.5 B".